# How do I securely process textarea data going in and out of the database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

** Update - following the link that deceze kindly posted to a similar question lead me to a great article by deceze here [The Great Escapism](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) which gave me all the answers I needed. To anyone finding this question due to similar issues I urge you to read this article **

I'm allowing users to enter information through a textarea on my site.

I'm aware that there is a security risk whenever a user can enter information into a site.

I want to be able to preserve whitespace / newlines from their entry but I'm also mindful of stripping HTML tags etc out of their input.

I have written a function that replaces `\r\n` with `<br/>` before the data retrieved from the database gets outputted to the browser (I also stripslashes before I output to the browser).

I have a function that will strip out HTML tags from the entered text that I can run before putting the user entry into the database.

I'm unsure if this is all that I need to do? Does anyone have either a list of checks I need to do before putting user-entered info into the database and then before displaying it in a browser? Or even a set of sanitising functions that they use for this?

I've looked at `esc_html()` and `sanitize_text_field()` and `filter_var($output, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES)` but I'm really unsure when I should be using what function?

Help much appreciated :-)

Comment: What does your code look like to actually put it in the database. There can be security risks there too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql_real_escape_string() to prevent sql-injection. You can find a good basic tutorial [here](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)